# Show Google Analytics on my page

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I've been looking into this for the past few hours and I'm wondering if it's possible to show `google analytics` on my page. I would like to show some of the information from my GA account like some WordPress plugins do (example: [Google Analytics Dashboard for WP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/)). This page would only be viewed by certain people with security similar to a back-end where all files in the directory are password protected.

Here's what I do and don't want from this:

- I do need it to be shown in my page
- I would like to be able to choose what I want to show, but it's not required (choose visitorsor show user agents, but not the OS language, for exmaple)
- I don't need it to be real time, day-to-day is good enough

This is the best option since some people need to view the Google Analytics but I don't want to give them access to my Google account for obvious reasons.

I have found similar threads which there seem to be WordPress solutions, but this is not needed.

One post I found refered me to [Google's Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) but I don't see how this could be linked with my GA Account.

Comment: you can just give read only access to your analytics

Comment: [this js library could help](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html).

Comment: @Pete, Thanks for the quick reply. This seems to be what I need. However, I get the following error: `403 User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile` when I try to configure it. I see in the Google Analytics Admin area I can add permissions to email adresses, but what if I want this to be general? Do I say "use this email adress to view the charts"? I doubt this would be a viable option.

Comment: I think you would need to set up a generic account that had read only access and if the user is logged on your site allow them to view the dashboard using the generic log in.  If you are wanting specific views for each user then you may need to look for something else

Answer (score 2):

I would use Google's [superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) to publicly display your Google Analytics data. The video on the reference page should get you all setup.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the complexity of this question, I would point to [Carmen's article *Monitoring Ecommerce Health*](http://www.clearclues.com/google-analytics-api-monitor-ecommerce-health/) that exactly describes what you need to do: use GA API and Visualization API and publish the stats/charts publicly.